# Objective C- Push Notifications not working with Cloudkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, cloudkit

I have an app that I'm building, and I'm trying to keep track of a subscription using Cloudkit. I have a RecordType called Notifications with one field of type String called NotificationText. For some reason, when I add a new record, the app does not receive it. Here's what I have done so far:

1. Registered for Cloudkit in the "Capabilities" section of the app.
2. Added the Required background modes key to the info.plist file for remote-notifications
3. Saved the Subscription to the database using:

   ```
   CKSubscription *subscription = [[CKSubscription alloc]
                                   initWithRecordType:@"Notifications"
                                   predicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES]
                                   options:CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordCreation];

   CKNotificationInfo *notificationInfo = [CKNotificationInfo new];
   notificationInfo.alertLocalizationKey = @"NotificationText";
   notificationInfo.shouldBadge = YES;
   notificationInfo.soundName = @"";

   subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo;
   [publicDB saveSubscription:subscription
            completionHandler:^(CKSubscription *subscription, NSError *error) {
                if (error)
                    [self handleError:error];

                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"sub"];

            }
    ];
   ```
4. Requested permission from the user to send push notifications using:

   ```
   UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
   UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert categories:nil];
   [application registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
   [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
   ```
5. Implemented the `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(non null NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(non null void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler;` in the AppDelegate.m file.

Now I go into the Cloudkit Dashboard and create a new record of RecordType Notifications, and nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

After much searching and banging my head against a wall, I found my problem.

PUSH NOTIFICATIONS DO NOT WORK ON SIMULATORS!

I hooked up an iPod to the app and, bang! Notification was received.